# Embedded questions with "tell me"

Tags: difference, embedded-clauses

I heard in a song this phrase, “Tell me how did you get so cold” and I think that's an embedded question, isn’t it?
But it should be written like this: “Tell me how you got so cold.” or am I wrong?
The song is: Cold-Maroon 5
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right: without any punctuation the sentence should be "Tell me how you got so cold.” But if it is punctuated like this: "Tell me - how did you get so cold?" or perhaps "Tell me: how did you get so cold?" it becomes a little less brusque. "Tell me" is often used to introduce a question in this way.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I looked at the lyrics, and it was without any punctuation, I guess it's informal speaking. Thank you!

Comment: Songwriters do not care about punctuation because songs are not meant to be read. Furthermore, the song lyrics that are published are typically written down by a person who did not write the song—an assistant of some kind. Worse, the lyrics you read on the Internet are usually written down by a person unrelated to the songwriter—someone like you or me. Not only do they miss any intended punctuation—they often choose the wrong words.

Answer (score 1):

In general, song lyrics follow different rules. If lyrics can be massaged to create better rhythm or rhyme, it will be done.

As was already mentioned, "Tell me, how did you get so cold" is correct, or "Tell me: how did you get so cold", or "Tell me how you got so cold".